# Download and create sqlite db from cvs/txt file

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am trying to download a operator specific db when the app is first time opening.
Since its operator specific, I cannot bundle this db as part of apk.

I have implemented a way to use DownloadManager to download the my_operator_specif_db.db and then reading it through SQLiteAssetHelper.

The size of the db is 23 mb. Since I am using "Accept-Encoding: gzip" in the headers, it will download zipped version of this db which is 8.3 mb. Still 8.3 mb transfer takes time to download on poor internet connection. Instead of this db, if I download a flat csv file with the same contents it comes around 13mb RAW and 3.8 mb zipped.

Effectively, I can make the download double times faster if I have a logic to load the flat csv file to an empty sqlite db.

Any suggestions on this approach?
How to load a csv file into db?

Comment: Your bottleneck is the size of the database, 8.3Mb, with the approach you are trying to do you just reduce by half the time, but you are not really making the different. Isn't too much complication to not really solve the problem just mitigate? The only thing that comes to my mind to your specific question is to read the file and create your own db in the apk.

Answer (score 0):

23 MB is not that much if what you're downloading is crucial for the app to function properly and you can always make it so that it is downloaded using wi-fi only(usually fast enough) That being said, you do want to keep the downloads to a minimum so what you can do is build the db from a raw text file(or .csv if that's what you have).

In my own opinion, if you're going to download something more than 1 MB, just get the gzipped db, it saves hassle. I'm saying this because downloading anything on a slow connection will be slow.